# Powering multiple hdds to work with raspberry pi 4

Tags: power-supply, usb-power, hard-drive

I have a rpi4 with the default 5v 3A charger. However, when I hook up all my usb peripherals (2 mechanical hdd and a cc2531) I run into power limitations and things do not work properly.

I am thinking of a solution as below where the pi is hooked up to the power adapter on its own. I happen to have a usb c hub that has a power in option. So if I hook in another power brick to the input of the usb hub, connect the hdds to the hub,and connect the usb c end of the hub to the pi with a USB C to USB A cable would it work without issue? I'm a bit hesitant to try without confirmation as I don't wanna burn out devices ;)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [many Q&A here in RPi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=self+powered+hub) that discuss various technical aspects of USB hubs. In your case (based on your question), it seems the key feature you need is a [`self-powered` USB hub - vs a `host-powered` hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub#Power). In summary, the `self-powered` hub will provide power to the drives that are plugged into the hub, thus saving capacity of your RPi power supply.

If you can find a self-powered hub that supplies 2 amps at 5V in a single port, that will probably be sufficient to power your RPi 4 under most scenarios. Note that [the "official" recommendation for a supply for the RPi 4 is for 5V and 3 amps.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#power-supply), but the basis for this recommendation has never been disclosed. In other words, 5V and 2 amps will cover you in most situations.

The RPi 4 is the only RPi that uses a USB-C connector. However, there is no electrical advantage to powering the RPi 4 with a USB-C power source because the RPi 4 will take only a 5VDC (nominal) input - same as USB-A. The RPi 4 is "wired" such that it will not allow power delivery at any voltage above 5 V (nominal). So yes - if you have a self-powered, USB-C compliant port, it is safe to connect it to the RPi 4.

But once again, having the ability to source 2 amps at 5VDC is the key. Note that some USB-C power sources will claim the ability to serve as a 100 Watt charger for laptops, etc. Know that this jargon is irrelevant to powering an RPi 4. That said, if you wish to delve deeper into the [USB Power Delivery Specifications](https://www.usb.org/usb-charger-pd), you could start with this [excellent Q&A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/159552).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am thinking of a setup like this: https://ibb.co/XXpnZ7S. The concern is if the 2nd power source will cause issues with the Pi? (which from your response feels like a no?) and the second is if the USB hub (which is a mobile OTG style hub) suitable for this purpose?

Comment: The setup/block diagram in your picture looks reasonable, and should cause no problems for your RPi. I'm afraid I can't offer an informed opinion on the hub itself, however, assuming it meets USB specifications, I can't see any reason why it should not work.

Comment: This is the usb hub that I have, and believe it should be usb compliant. https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07MY1X9T9/ref=cm_sw_r_apan_glt_i_NEJZEKJ9RFREA2ENE1EG?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1